# I receive this error when trying to Import a DXF File, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "AutoCAD Binary DXF'

Tags: python

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\__init__.py", line 45, in readfile
    return readfile_as_asc(filename, options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\__init__.py", line 60, in readfile_as_asc
    return _read_encoded_file(filename, options, encoding=get_encoding())
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\__init__.py", line 57, in get_encoding
    info = dxfinfo(fp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\tags.py", line 456, in dxfinfo
    tag = next(tagreader)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\tags.py", line 154, in stream_tagger
    x = next_tag()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\tags.py", line 140, in next_tag
    code = stream.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\python\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 245: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\__init__.py", line 67, in _read_encoded_file
    dwg = Drawing(fp, options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\drawing.py", line 32, in __init__
    sections = Sections(tagreader, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\sections.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._setup_sections(tagreader, drawing)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\sections.py", line 38, in _setup_sections
    for section in iterchunks(tagreader, stoptag='EOF', endofchunk='ENDSEC'):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\defaultchunk.py", line 29, in iterchunks
    tag = next(tagreader)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\tags.py", line 154, in stream_tagger
    x = next_tag()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber\tags.py", line 144, in next_tag
    return DXFTag(int(code.rstrip('\r\n')), value.rstrip('\r\n'))  # without line ending
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AutoCAD Binary DXF'
```

Comment: Hello. Seems like your dxf file is either corrupted or in a format that is not supported by Blender's importer. Try saving it in another version